# Dividing the list in Python and print the combinations

Tags: python-3.x

If i have a list in python, i want to divide the list into sub lists of some size 's' and then produce all the combinations of the sub_lists of size 2.

E.g :

```
Input: List = ['1','2','3','4']
sub-list size s = 3
```

My Output should be :

```
Sub-List-1 = ['1','2','3']
Combinations-1 = [('1','2'),('1','3'),('2','3')]

Sub-List-2 = ['2','3','4']
Combinations-2 = [('2','3'),('2','4'),('3','4')]
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
combination_list = []     
while (myList):      
    sub_list = []    
    sub_list.append(myList[:s])     
    myList = myList[s:]
    combination_list.append(combinations(sub_list, 2))
```

My Logic is :

- Create an empty List for Combination
- While my original List is not empty

  - Create an empty list for Sub lists
  - Append the s items to the sub lists
  - Remove s items from my original List(the items present in my sub list)
  - Produce the combinations of elements in my sub Lists

But i am not getting an expected output. Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result_list = []
combination_list = []
for i in range(len(myList)-s+1):
    result_list.clear()
    for j in range(i,i+s):
        result_list.append(myList[j])
    for i in combinations(result_list, 2):
        combination_list.append((i[0],i[1]))
```

I got what is expected with the above piece of code!!But if you think it can be improved or there's something wrong with the code, please let me know!!

Comment: I got what is expected with the above piece of code!!But if you think it can be improved or there's something wrong with the code, please let me know!!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, i hope it helps

```
import itertools

mylist = ['1','2','3','4']
ls =[]
for i in range(0,int(len(mylist)/2)):
        ls.append([mylist[i],mylist[i+1],mylist[i+2]])

print(len(ls))    /just getting the length to know how many sublist you have
sub1 = ls[0]
sub2 = ls[1]

comb1 =[]
comb2 =[]

//using itertools
comb1 = list(itertools.combinations(sub1,2))
comb2 = list(itertools.combinations(sub2,2))
print("combinations")
print(comb1)
print(comb2)
```

> // if you want to use any import then you can use for-loop to do the
>   logic

```
ncomb = []
for i in range(len(sub1)-1):
    for a in range(i,len(sub1)-1):
        ncomb.append((sub1[i],sub1[a+1]))
print(ncomb) // output the same [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

> //or better with List comprehension

```
lsize = len(sub1)
listcomp = [(sub1[x],sub1[y+1]) for x in range(lsize-1) for y in range(x,lsize-1)]
print(listcomp) // output the same [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

> combinations
>
> [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
>
> [('2', '3'), ('2','4'), ('3', '4')]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply!!I did it in a different way!!I got what is expected!!I even tried what you asked me to!!It worked!!Thanks again!!